# Getting the value of a dropdown box and adding them

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have two dropdown boxes and I want to make it so that when the user selects the second box, it runs an onChange method and adds the value with the value of the first dropdown box.

Example:

```
<select class="form-control" id="dropbox1" changeHiddenInput()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="dropbox2" changeHiddenInput()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input id="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 5px" name="btnLogin" value="" />
```

This is what I have in my javascript and it's not working.

```
    function changeHiddenInput() {
    var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1').value;
    var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2').value;
    console.log(dropdown1);
    console.log(dropdown2);
    var var1 = parseInt(dropdown1);
    var var2 = parseInt(dropdown2);
    var a = var1+var2;
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').value= a;
}
```

If 1 and 2 are selected. It'll change the button's value to 3.

Thanks!

Comment: it is pretty simple did you try something ?

Comment: Yea I tried this
' function changeHiddenInput() {
  var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1').value;
  var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2').value;
  console.log(dropdown1);
  console.log(dropdown2);
  var var1 = parseInt(dropdown1);
  var var2 = parseInt(dropdown2);
  var a = var1+var2;
  document.getElementById('submitbutton').value= a;
 }'

Comment: *"it runs an onChange method"* That's not what your HTML does though. `changeHiddenInput()` just does nothing. Also, if you expect useful answers, you have to be a bit more precise than "it's not working". We already that, because otherwise you won't ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('dropbox2').onchange= function(){
    var val1=document.getElementById('dropbox1').value;
    var val2=document.getElementById('dropbox2').value;
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').value=parseInt(val1)+parseInt(val2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, changed it. Guess I should head to sleep

Answer (score 0):

Use the following HTML and Script

```
<select class="form-control" id="dropbox1" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="dropbox2" onchange="addDb()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<input id="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 5px" name="btnLogin" value="" />

<script>
function addDb() {
     var val1=document.getElementById('dropbox1').value;
    var val2=document.getElementById('dropbox2').value;
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').value=parseInt(val1)+parseInt(val2);
}
</script>
```

Here is a **[FiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wf3g2/170/)**

Answer (score 0):

the error is in your html code only.
`call changeHiddenInput function with onchange event  in  dropdown`

**html**

```
<select class="form-control" id="dropbox1" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="dropbox2" onchange ="changeHiddenInput();">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input id="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 5px" name="btnLogin" value="" />
```

**Java Script**

```
<script>
    function changeHiddenInput()
    {
      var val1 = document.getElementById('dropbox1').value;
      var val2 = document.getElementById('dropbox2').value;
      document.getElementById('submitbutton').value=parseInt(val1)+parseInt(val2);
    }
</script>
```